# Search doesn't allow exact phrase "[=1]"

Tags: support, search

Is there any additional advanced search operators that would enforce the existence of `[=1]` in search results? Using double quote `"[=1]"` does not work. I couldn't find relevant info in https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

In particular, I'm looking to search in http://tex.stackexchange.com where such argument can show up in the code.

This particular expression currently cannot be searched with Google nor Bing advanced search operators.

Comment: TL;DR: not possible, maybe a bug, maybe just a missing feature. :(